# Creating pages on sharepoint site with microsoft graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Currently I'm trying to create a page on a newly created site with some dummy data. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sitepage-create?view=graph-rest-beta it should be possible to create a page using json like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/tenant.sharepoint.com%2Cee2667f8-2bae-460e-944b-613773baaa03%2C8c0054a6-6e0e-49cd-be6d-4c4c0aaf644e/pages HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <token>
User-Agent: Java-Client
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept: application/json, text/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 167

{"name":"Testpage21.aspx","publishingState":{"level":"published","versionId":"0.1"},"title":"Testpage21","webParts":[{"type":"rte","innerHTML":"<h1>Hello!</h1>"}]}
```

as you can see nothing fancy. Unfortunatly when issueing this request I receive the following error response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 1dba7669-1318-488a-a416-63fddbdfcda1
client-request-id: 1dba7669-1318-488a-a416-63fddbdfcda1
Duration: 833.8091
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 15:13:15 GMT
Content-Length: 236

{
  "error": {
    "code": "generalException",
    "message": "General exception while processing",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "1dba7669-1318-488a-a416-63fddbdfcda1",
      "date": "2019-01-04T15:13:16"
    }
  }
}
```

When I remove the webparts property from my initial requests the POST succeeds I get response like this:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites('tenant.com%2Cee2667f8-2bae-460e-944b-613773baaa03%2C8c0054a6-6e0e-49cd-be6d-4c4c0aaf644e')/pages/$entity","eTag":"\"{DA2C2C0C-2222-4F11-917E-7B4BBFE8AC99},3\"","id":"da2c2c0c-2222-4f11-917e-7b4bbfe8ac99","lastModifiedDateTime":"2019-01-04T15:08:12Z","name":"Testpagina2.aspx","webUrl":"SitePages/Testpagina2.aspx","title":"Testpagina2","pageLayout":"Article","parentReference":{"siteId":"ee2667f8-2bae-460e-944b-613773baaa03"},"contentType":{"id":"0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C411800A19AB965C0D2B54C82DFCC03DBE6A732","name":"Sitepagina"},"publishingState":{"level":"checkout","versionId":"0.1"}}
```

But ofcourse I would like to add at least some content ( html ) to the page before I publish it.

Could someone tell me if the creation of pages using Graph is not yet fully functional? Or that I'm missing something.

p.s. what kind of webparts are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we have a bug in our docs (assigned to be fixed), the "innerHTML" property should be wrapped in a "data" property like the properties of other web parts.  Here's what your payload should look like:

```
{
  "name":"Testpage21.aspx",
  "publishingState":{"level":"published","versionId":"0.1"},
  "title":"Testpage21",
  "webParts": [{
      "type":"rte",
      "data": {
        "innerHTML":"<h1>Hello!</h1>"
      }
  }]
}
```

In terms of what web parts are available any part should work but we have not documented the data structures associated with them for the current Beta release.  That generally makes the API most useful with your own custom web parts where you already know what properties you need to have in the data block.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try it shortly. Are there somewhere basic examples on how we can, for instance, create a set of wiki pages with rich content?

p.s. i'm no sharepoint developer. I just started to work with office 365 / Graph api

Comment: Wiki pages are an interesting twist.  In SharePoint there are (for better and worse) many different types of "pages".  The Pages API in Microsoft Graph only allows you to create what we call Site Pages or Modern Pages.  These are the new default type of page you get if you're building a new Team site or Communication site.

Wiki pages are one of the older types and don't really fall under what the new Beta API can do.  That said, the new pages are a lot better and will ultimately provide a much richer capability than the legacy page types.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.