# General Exception when creating Site Pages through Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm having an issue where i'm receiving a general exception when trying to create site pages through Microsoft Graph API beta endpoints even in Graph Explorer, I'm at a loss at what it could be as i'm using the sample provided in the documentation.

I'm using the following request:

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{siteId}/pages`

```
{
    "name":"Events.aspx",
    "title":"Team Events",
    "publishingState": {
        "level":"checkedOut",
        "versionId":"0.1"
     },
     "webParts":[
         {
             "type":"rte",
             "innerHTML":"<p>Here are the teams upcoming events:</p>"
         }
    ]
}
```

and its returning this response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "generalException",
        "message": "General exception while processing",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-18T05:11:16",
            "request-id": "09efb46d-f393-46c8-a8ff-450815c85d35",
            "client-request-id": "0ef11da8-832e-47d8-ed5d-1192343af8fa"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, and stumbled across this StackOverflow post.

[Creating pages on sharepoint site with microsoft graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041700/creating-pages-on-sharepoint-site-with-microsoft-graph)

Basically, there is an issue with the docs. The `innerHTML` key needs to be wrapped inside a `data` key.

So you would be calling the following:

```json
{
    "name":"Events.aspx",
    "title":"Team Events",
    "publishingState": {
        "level":"checkedOut",
        "versionId":"0.1"
     },
     "webParts":[
         {
             "type":"rte",
             "data": {
                "innerHTML":"<p>Here are the teams upcoming events:</p>"
            }
         }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making your request exactly as shown in the question, the issue may be the URL. The `{siteId}` part of your POST URL is a placeholder.

**You will want to replace `{siteId}` with your site ID**

For example, if your `siteID` is **ABC123**, then the URL for your POST would be:
**https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/ABC123/pages**